# shuffling between a set of open source files

Tags: buffers, minibuffer, projectile

What would be the easiest way of shuffling between a few source files, usually of the same type, say .py or .js.   C-x C-b and selecting gets a little tedious once your open buffers list grows.  I would like the following options if possible

- toggle between two files only,  same window, just going back and forth
- all open buffers filtered by the same file extension as current one
- all open buffers filtered by files from the same projectile project

I don't mind using a little bit of elisp code in my configuration with my own shortcuts.

Any pointers will be appreciated.  I currently use magit, projectile, helm, neotree, ivy at a high level to manage multiple git repos

Edit: Till i get really comfortable with shortcuts i will be ok to use my mouse a little bit.  So an option which is more mouse friendly or even mouse dependent is also an ok option for now.

Comment: Please narrow your question to cover only one of the "options" you want to know about. You can post separate questions for each of them, if you like.

Comment: Oops, I figured there would be a common solution or package to address all of these :)

Answer (score 1):

You might find better answers elsewhere (and many people will have other opinions), so I will be brief. See [chapter 20.1 Creating and Selecting Buffers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Buffer.html) of the Emacs manual for several options.

First, `C-x b` (aka `switch-to-buffer`, not `C-x C-b` aka `list-buffers`) is what I use most often. It prompts you to input the name of a buffer to switch to, but the default is always the next most recently used buffer so simply hitting ENTER will take you right to it. This is how I normally swap back and forth between two buffers.

For dealing with projects, `C-x p b` (`project-switch-to-buffer`) is the same but limits the completion to just buffers from the current project. See [chapter 29.2.2 Project Commands That Operate on Buffers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Project-Buffer-Commands.html) in the Emacs manual.